# Java consumer/producer

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class Queue {
    int value = 0;
    boolean isEmpty = true;
    public synchronized void put(int n){
        if (!isEmpty){
            try {
                System.out.println("producer is waiting");
                wait();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        value += n;
        isEmpty = false;
        System.out.println("The number of products："+value);
        notifyAll();
    }
    public synchronized void get(){
        if (isEmpty){
            try{
                System.out.println("customer is waiting");
                wait();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        value --;
        if(value<1){
            isEmpty = true;
        }
        System.out.println("there are "+value+" left");
        notifyAll();
    }
}


public class Producer extends Thread{
    private Queue queue;
    public Producer(String name,Queue queue){
        super(name);
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            queue.put(i+1);
        }
    }

}

public class Producer extends Thread{
    private Queue queue;
    public Producer(String name,Queue queue){
        super(name);
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            queue.put(i+1);
        }
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue queue = new Queue();
        Thread customer1 = new Customer("customer1",queue);
        Thread producer1 = new Producer("producer1",queue);
        customer1.setPriority(4);
        producer1.setPriority(7);
        producer1.start();
        customer1.start();

    }

}
```

outputs:

```
 
The number of products：1    
producer is waiting    
there are 0left    
customer is waiting    
The number of products：2    
producer is waiting    
there are 1left    
there are 0left    
customer is waiting    
The number of products：3    
producer is waiting    
there are 2left    
there are 1left    
there are 0left     
customer is waiting   
The number of products：4    
producer is waiting    
there are 3left    
there are 2left    
there are 1left    
there are 0left    
customer is waiting    
The number of products：5    
there are 4left    
there are 3left    
there are 2left    
there are 1left    
there are 0left    
customer is waiting
```

I don't know why the order of outputs are like this.

Why doesn't it output the result like

```
The number of products：3  
producer is waiting      
there are 2left    
The number of products: 6       
there are 5left            
The number of products: 10     
there are 9left    
The number of products: 15        
there are 14left
```

Comment: Why do you need to multithread that?

Comment: I just want to know why it doesn't work this way.

Comment: process synch is not guaranteed.

Comment: It always outputs the same thing, and there is no change in the order.

Comment: Your producer puts 15 "items" in to the queue.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Why is the order of execution fixed? The producer can execute only when the customer has completed the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't check for your condition after beeing notified.

You do a

```
if (condition){
  wait();
}
increment();
```

While your thread could be notified from another context, it will not check, if the condition still exists or has been solved by another thread and do the increment anyway.
Correct would be to recheck your condition on wake up, something like:

```
while (condition){
  wait();
}
increment();
```